# ember.js: extend Ember.TextField and only update value property on enter key

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm looking to create a text field just like the one using input helper except it behaves slightly different: it will not update the property it is bound to until the enter key is pressed.  I extended the component and tried to override functions that might update the property as such:

```
InputTextSoftComponent = Ember.TextField.extend(
  keyPress:->
    console.log("keypress")
  propertyDidChange:->
    console.log('propChange')
  didInsertElement:->
    console.log('insert')
  modelChangedValue:->
    console.log('changeval')

)
```

The component works just like a normal text field now, which I was pleasantly surprised with

```
{{input-text-soft id="height-input" class="position-inputs" type="text" value=controller.activeRegion.width}}
```

However, I can't stop the changes in the text field from updating the value target.  How can I prevent this and achieve a kind of soft binding so that the input only updates the property on enter key ?  I'm looking for a solution specific to Ember CLI and the use of components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a different bound property. An alias for your real property. Bind your textfield to that property. Update the real property from the alias only if enter is pressed. Pseudo:

```
{{input-text-soft id="height-input" realValueBinding="controller.activeRegion.width" value=newWidth...}}

keyPress() {
  if (keyCode == xx)
     this.set('realValue', this.get('newWidth'))
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this so I don't have to create 'dirty' variables for each input outside of the component.  Presumable I would have to copy the value activeRegion.width and put it in another variable newWidth, correct ?

Comment: oh, maybe I could make the component bind 'value' to an intermediary variable which is initialized to the value of the realValue so I didn't have to pass value in

Comment: of course you can initialize newValue with whatever you want. But binding the textfield value to a property, will make that property change. So there is no other way than creating a different property, if you dont want the original property to be changed.